# Product of a positive increasing function and a decreasing one

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a question which seems trivial, but I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

> Let $f:[0,1]\to (0,\infty)$ be an increasing function and let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $fg$ is decreasing in $[0,1].$ Then $g$ is decreasing in $[0,1].$

Is it true or false? Or what assumption can be imposed in order to make the statement true?

We may give the assumption on $f$ and $g$ which are differentiable functions.

Actually, I'd like to prove the following assertion

> Let $f(t)$ be a positive increasing function and $g$ be a sign-changing function such that $g>0$ for $(0,a)$ and $g<0$ for $(a,1)$. If $fg$ is decreasing in $(0,1),$ then $g$ is decreasing in $(0,1).$

I would be grateful if you give any comment for my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your comment, although I don't understand it completely. Would you give it more detail? Note that $1/f$ is a positive decreasing function.

Comment: Sorry.  I misread the question.  Having trouble with my new glasses.

Comment: I added a full answer with an explicit counterexample to your second claim. If this answer is acceptable, please upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of increasing and decreasing,

$$ f(x) \text{ is increasing } \longleftrightarrow\frac{df}{dx}>0\\
f(x) \text{ is decreasing } \longleftrightarrow\frac{df}{dx}<0
$$

Therefore, $\frac{df}{dx}>0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(fg)<0$. By the product rule, $f\frac{dg}{dx}+g\frac{df}{dx}<0\to\frac{dg}{dx}<-\frac gf\frac{df}{dx}$. By what we have been given, $f(x)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$ are both positive, so as **long as $g(x)$ is positive for every $x$ in your interval**, $\frac{dg}{df} < 0$, which means $g(x)$ is decreasing. If $g(x)<0$ for any $x\in[0,1]$, then your conclusion is false.

Easiest counter example, let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x-2$. $f(x)g(x)=x^2-2x$ and $\frac{d(fg)}{dx}=2x-2$, which is negative for all $x<1$, so it's decreasing in the interval.

**Added to the Question:**

For $g(x)$ to be a function such that $g(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,a)$ and $g(x)<0$ for $x\in(a,1)$, $g(x)$ must necessarily go from a positive number to a negative number, which means that it has to either be decreasing for some interval containing $a$ or it must have a discontinuity.

A discontinuous counterexample was given in the comments, namely

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x, &x<a\\x - 2, &x\geq a\end{cases}$$

This function is always increasing, so $g(x)$ must also be specified to be continuous or the conclusion that $g(x)$ is decreasing is false.

For a continuous function, $g(x)$ must be decreasing around $x=a$, but it doesn't have to be decreasing anywhere else. For example, $g(x)=(x-b)(x-a)$, where $b=1 + \frac a2$ which decreases for $x<\frac {a + b}2$ and increases for $x>\frac {a + b}2$, and $f(x)=x^3$. $\frac{d(fg)}{dx}=5x^4-4(a+b)x^3-3abx^2=5x^4-4x^3-6ax^3-3(ab)x^2$. So now, we need to find all the values of $a$ for which the derivative is less than zero.

$$\begin{align}
5x^4-4x^3-6ax^3-3abx^2 &< 0 &(\text{substitution})\\
5x^4-4x^3-6ax^3-3abx^2 &< 5x^4-4x^3-6ax^2 &(a, b, x^2 > 0)\\
x^3(5x-4-6a) &< 0 \\
5x-4 &< 6a &((x^3>0)(\forall x \in(0,1))\\
a &> \frac16 &(\max x = 1)
\end{align}$$

In other words, as long as $a>\frac16$, $fg$ will be decreasing on $(0,1)$, so we'll pick an $a$ greater than $\frac16$. We also need to find out for what values of $a$ is $\frac{a + b}2<1$, which is simply

$$\begin{align}
a + \frac a2 + 1 &< 2\\
\frac32a &< 1\\
a &< \frac23
\end{align}$$

So $a$ also has to be less than $\frac23$.

Since $f(x)$ is positive and increasing for $x\in(0,1)$, $fg$ is decreasing for $x\in(0,1)$, and $g(x)$ is a smooth function that is positive for $x<a$ and negative for $x>a$, but is increasing for $x\in\left(\frac{a + b}2,1\right)$ as long as $a\in\left(\frac16,\frac23\right)$, we have a known counterexample to the statement that $g(x)$ must be decreasing on $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question. Is it possible to make the similar counterexample for sign-changing function $g$? More precisely, $g>0$ for $(0,a)$ and $g<0$ for $(a,1).$

Comment: $g(x)$ would have to be decreasing, discontinuous, or not monotone for it to be positive for $x<a$ and negative for $x>a$. If you want a discontinuity, $$g(x)=\begin{cases}x, & x < a \\ x-2, &x>a\end{cases}$$.

Comment: Actually, I don't want a discontinuity function $g$. Anyway, for $x<a,$ $fg$ is increasing. Do you define another $f$?

Comment: I would say definition of increasing is $f(b)>f(a)$ if $b>a$; that definition works even if $f$ is not differentiable

Comment: I apologize, but could you be more specific? What is the exact proposition you want to prove?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are right. But differentiable functions are sufficient for my interest.

Comment: I didn’t think over your new answer. But in $(f(x)g(x))’$, you omitted the $x^2$ term.

Comment: @0706 Including the $x^2$ term decreases the lower bound, as the $x^2$ term is negative for all $x\in(0,1)$. The last paragraph is still true.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thanks for your help.